# add string to text file with verification

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I have a code:

```
$fp = fopen("/path/to/file", "w");
fwrite($fp, $var);
fclose($fp);
```

I need to do - add text string write in a text file without spaces with verification sample text.txt

```
foo
bar
foo_bar
```

If **foo** already exist in file - nothing to add.
Add a line of text in a file, but with check, if text is already there, example **foo** there is then nothing to add. If i add **foofoo** add it to text.txt

Comment: unclear what you're asking
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: file_put_contents() with FILE_APPEND?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read into an array and check for the value.  If it doesn't exist, append it (with a newline `\n`):

```
$lines = file("/path/to/file", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if(!in_array($var, $lines) {
    file_put_contents("/path/to/file", "\n$var", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is not what I posted.  Notice `file()` instead of `file_get_contents()`.